# how to using dropbox-cli?

Tags: command-line, sync, dropbox, console

There is a command-line-interface (cli) to run dropbox from the console. Is there any tutorial or guide on how to use it?

Comment: Make sure to check out ['Programmatically sync dropbox without daemon running'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349851/programmatically-sync-dropbox-without-daemon-running/349865#349865) to learn how to perform a one-off dropbox sync.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use Dropbox Uploader, download the script and make it executable.

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/master/dropbox_uploader.sh
$ chmod +x dropbox_uploader.sh
```

To list all contents in the top-level directory:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list
```

To list all contents in a specific folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list Documents/manuals
```

To upload a local file to a remote Dropbox folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload snort.pdf Documents/manuals
```

To download a remote file from Dropbox to a local file:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh download Documents/manuals/mysql.pdf ./mysql.pdf
```

To download an entire remote folder from Dropbox to a local folder:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh download Documents/manuals ./manuals
```

To create a new remote folder on Dropbox:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh mkdir Documents/whitepapers
```

To delete an entire remote folder (including all its contents) on Dropbox:

```
$ ./dropbox_uploader.sh delete Documents/manuals
```

You can check this site :

[Site](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli)

It may be helpful .

Comment: Yes, I have found this site earlier, thank you; just in the repositories is dropbox-cli package and I think that to use in console need know how to work with this package.  I will go to read and understand, maybe your link helped

Comment: Nux, there says "Dropbox Uploader is.. an online file sharing, synchronization and backup service" but I never found how to synchronize folder, there is only upload, download, copy, del commands..   but for my problem (small library) requires synchronization of folders

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of, it's available in a terminal with `man dropbox` after you've installed it. Though it does mention

```
   In the future there will be full command line support including  linking
   accounts and setting preferences from the dropbox command.
```

So I'm not sure if you can do absolutely everything from the command line.

Comment: trying get any help in my system (man, --help, info) but it is'n. Just i need some worked dropbox, because after update v3.0.3 it not started

Comment: When I installed the `dropbox` package (on Linux Mint), I was able to see it's man page with `man dropbox` in a terminal, if that's the one you installed it should work. But if you're able to run a graphic desktop I think synchronizing a folder with dropbox might be a lot easier.

Comment: I agree with you, but I work in a non-ubuntu system (Manjaro, based on ArchLinux) and therefore did not work for me; here at all, much depends on the experience, knowledge, "moon phase" and is set with minimal default settings. And turned to this forum because there is a good community.

  With dropbox understood - it starts and functions (if you look at 'htop') simply does not show an icon in the system tray / broken after upgrade, will have to repair